# HTML and CSS lock screen for mobile web application

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website, lockscreen

I'm building a single page, offline html5 web application using jquery mobile, backbone, underscore and tbd templating engine.

I'd like to create a lockscreen that looks similar to the native iPhone lockscreen.  Before I go reinvent the wheel has anyone seen anything like this before? I haven't been able to find an example of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to implement an unlock slider? This has been done before: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/implementing-iphone-slider-unlock-with-input-type-range

Comment: I'm looking for an example implementation of the screen that appears after the unlock slider- the "enter passcode" screen

Comment: *tongue in cheek sarcasm* In other words, looking for something that in no way will be used to circumvent security and be used for phishing attacks.

Comment: this is for a LOB app, the view will be branded.  The intent is to streamline the process of entering user credentials.  I doesn't make sense to force the users to type their full user id and password each time they access the mobile app- especially since the mobile app doesn't expose the same level of sensitive data thats exposed in the mainline app.

Comment: @Matt: "Surprisingly, the only mobile OS to implement this input type seems to be BlackBerry OS 6."

Comment: @Matt -- http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xpmRW/ :-D

Comment: Note that input type="range" now works in iOS 5 :)

Comment: Checkout this awesome ipad in html5/css3/jquery http://alexw.me/ipad2/
Try looking around in it maybe you'll get what you want ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Oh no, it's an old question!

Add a fixed-position, hidden `div` to your page. When you need to activate the lock screen, use jQuery to programmatically show it:

**CSS**

```
div#lockscreen {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hypothetical activation control
    $("#lock").click(function() {
        $("#lockscreen").css("width", "100%");
        $("#lockscreen").css("height", "100%");
        $("#lockscreen").css("z-index", "1000");
        //or dynamically generate z-index value
        $("#lockscreen").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Update - don't use `jQuery.prototype.fadeIn`. This executes on JavaScript's event loop and can perform poorly on constrained environments. Use CSS transitions if possible, as they are optimised and accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's been dredged up now, so I might aswell add this. Use `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />` on a text field to get a numeric input. Not quite the same, but easier than using a full keyboard, and easier than coding the whole keypad yourself.

Comment: Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html